# Navigation Bar and Tab Bar when rotating

Tags: ios, tabbar, navigationbar

I have four controllers for the tab bar and it's views, when I rotate phone I want it to call the method shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation for only one of the controllers but it calls the method for all of them.

How can I call shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation for only one of the controllers?

Answer (score 1):

You don't "call" these methods, those are methods that are being called for any class that inherits from UIViewController.
There is no reason to want them not to be called anyway. 
What you can do is decide to override any of these methods for any of your controller.
The method returns a boolean, if you return true, then the view is being rotated, if you return false, then it is not.

You can also decide to return YES/NO based on the orientation, in order to support one specific orientation

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
```

In this case, the view is being rotated only if the new orientation is portrait.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you **JP Hribovsek**, I solved it using `beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications` that notifies me when the device´s orientation is changed. For example:

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self 
                                         selector: @selector(deviceRotate:) 
                                             name: UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification 
                                           object: nil];

-(void) deviceRotate: (NSNotification*) notification
{
    UIDeviceOrientation interfaceOrientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];

    if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {    
        NSlog(@"Landscape");    
    }
}
```